# Register webhooks on another PayPal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

I understand how to register webhooks for all kinds of events within my OWN PayPal account. I need something different: I want my users to authorize me to register a webhook for specific events in THEIR accounts.

The short story is that I want to place a service in the middle between participating users and merchants. So I imagine this could go one of two ways:

1. USER authorizes me to register webhooks for authorization events on his PayPal acct (typically PayPal Personal). I read the payload to identify transactions related to participating MERCHANTs.
2. MERCHANT authorizes me to register webhooks for authorization events on his PayPal acct (typically PayPal Pro/Business). I read the payload to identify transactions related to participating USERs.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Do it for the merchant accounts (2).

You'll need them to onboard and provide a REST clientid + secret so you can use those credentials to create transactions for them and register for the webhooks you want.